# Passing Interface to constructor of class implementing the Interface

Tags: java, android, twitter, jtwitter

I have a class Twitter which implements Interface Twitter.IHttpClient. 
Now contructor for Twitter uses same interface as paramter.

```
Twitter(java.lang.String name, Twitter.IHttpClient client);
```

How is that possible?
As interface Twitter.IHttpClient will be member of Twitter class itself and I can't create a Twitter class without it through constructor?
or

I am understanding wrongly?

Answer (score 2):

`Twitter.IHttpClient` is a static nested interface of the `Twitter` class.

As such, it is scoped statically and won't require an instance of `Twitter`.